# Is there any way to use Oracle instead of MySQL without changing existing code base in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, oracle

I developed an application in C, using MySQL. Now I wanted to migrate to Oracle, and don't want to make so many changes in code as well, like connecting to database and etc. 'liboramysql' a MySQL Client Library Driver for Oracle Database which is very useful in this case.

But a part of my entire code is written in Python as well, for which I need a similar lib or something similar to it. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: MySQL and Oracle are very different databases..

Comment: Yes, I know that MySQL and Oracle are two different databases. What I need is a way to connect to Oracle via mysql connector. 'liboramysql' does that job, but only if the code is in 'c' language. Is there any similar way in python?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DRDAA/mysql_driver.htm#DRDAA29191